# Using Indian debit cards in Nepal

Tags: india, debit-card, atm, nepal

Can I use my Indian debit cards in Nepal to withdraw cash from ATMs? In particular, I have an AXIS bank debit card. Can I use it freely for making payments as well as for withdrawing cash from ATMs in Nepal? If yes, what currency can I get from the ATMs?

Comment: Depends on the Bank and the issuing partner. You can definitely use Visa and Mastercard branded cards abroad (you might need to ask your bank to allow international transactions before you leave). RuPay cards may not work outside India.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes!

I hold an HDFC Debit card which is an Indian bank as well and I was able to use it in Nepal a year ago. However, before using it internationally you may I had to activate the card for International Usage and set its limit for international usage.

You may use it freely for making payments as well as for withdrawing cash from ATMs in Nepal. The currency may be local what you will be withdrawing from there. There might be some charges that you may have to bear such as cross-currency mark-up charges on foreign currency transactions and charges for non-use at Non bank international ATMs.

Do check this out with your bank.

Answer (score 0):

Nope there is some issue. Recently maybe a year ago till now the Indian cards DO NOT WORK in NEPAL! I tried several times in different ATMs. Both in Kathmandu and other places. Nor ICICI nor Axis nor CBI works. It is extremely infuriating. They were working fine before demonitization around 2 years ago than they stopped the service. It say the transaction could not be completed. Hope they will allow it again.